# DB2 Adapter for Ruby on Rails vs ActiveRecord JDBC Adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jdbc, db2, jruby, adapter

Could anyone point to me the differences and the benefits between using "DB2 Adapter for Ruby on Rails" and "Active Record JDBC Adapter"?

Generally, I am going to use the "jRUby on Rails" and "DB2 Express-C" and till now, I have thought the only way to connect IBM DB2 database with RoR application is using [ActiveRecord JDBC Adapter](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter).

Anyway on the [DB2 Express C](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express-c/download.html) download page, there is a link to [Rails Driver and Apdater for DB2](http://rubygems.org/gems/ibm_db) gem.

Which one I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use Jruby for your Web development then you can only use `ActiveRecord JDBC Adapter`

You can not use `IBM_DB` gem as it builds native C libraries as part of its install process. More details on this [here](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/GettingStarted)

Your `database.yml` can look like the following (as far as i can remember). Also you can include db2jcc.jar in $JRUBY_HOME/lib directory if you run into issues related to `CLASSPATH`

```
  development:
    adapter: jdbc
    driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    url: localhost:50001/devdb
    host: localhost
    port: 50001
    database: devdb
    username: username
    password: password
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Adding the db2jcc.jar file in my jruby/bin/ directory does not solve my issue. When I start my application I get the following message: "cannot load Java class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver". COuld you assist me on this?

Comment: sorry my mistake, copy db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar to jruby/lib directory. You are getting that error because you need the DB2 Universal JDBC driver jars in your classpath: